# How do I use erl_tidy and erl_lint?

Tags: erlang, lint

I know the docs explain these tools, but I don't understand the explanation. Can someone provide an example or two?

Comment: You should rarely (if ever) need to run erl_lint yourself. It's always being run when you compile a module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of `erl_tidy`, the simplest way - and the most direct, if you have one running in your source directory all the time anyway, is to use it directly from Eshell, as in

```
$ erl
1> m(erl_tidy).
% output snipped
2> erl_tidy:dir().  % recursively tidy the present directory and its children
% output snipped
3> erl_tidy:dir("", [{recursive, false}]).  % just the present directory
reading module `./bad.erl'.
made backup of file `./bad.erl'.
writing to file `./bad.erl'.
4>
```

In this case, `bad.erl` went from

```
-module(bad).
-compile(export_all).

bad(0)->1;bad(1)->2;bad(N)->3.bad()->0.
```

to the tidied

```
-module(bad).

-compile(export_all).

bad ( 0 ) -> 1 ; bad ( 1 ) -> 2 ; bad ( N ) -> 3 . bad ( ) -> 0 .
```

... well, it's not a magician :-)

`erl_tidy` can also be invoked through arguments to `erl`, as in

```
$ # unix prompt
$ erl -s erl_tidy dir
tidying directory `./wesnoth'.
tidying directory `./wesnoth/Vix'.
tidying directory `./wesnoth/Vix/utils'.
...
```

`erl_lint` however is *completely* different.  To understand how to use it, first understand what's going on in [this string evaluation example](http://www.trapexit.org/String_Eval).  `erl_lint` is designed to act on an intermediate representation of Erlang source, not on strings of it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to run erl_tidy() in preview mode so that it doesn't actually change the files?

Comment: Yes, to run erl_tidy without it changing any files (just printing info about changes), pass 'test' or '{test, true}' as option.  Note that it's been a long time since I wrote this program, so there are many things that it doesn't do. Tidier (http://tidier.softlab.ntua.gr/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) is much more capable.

Comment: I wrote a shell script that aliases ehrlich to erl_tidy:dir. https://github.com/mcandre/ehrlich